# Shiny UI distorted when minimized

Tags: css, r, shiny

So Im making a website and I have included a .css file to be able to move things more freely. I have made some items with position:relative and others I have used the absolutePanel(). I want to keep my layout as it is but when the window is resized it looks horrible. Any suggestions?

Comment: share some code. Its hard to give general tips. Try to use responsive design. Look into Bootstrap. Use "20%" instead of 30px and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should try to be a bit more specific on your question.
Some general tips though are instead of using pixels for the sizes of divs etc.(static design) use either percentages, `vh  & vw` (view height and view width of the window that are being displayed respectively) or media queries `@media`  (responsive design). To make your life a lot easier with responsive design though check out Bootstrap, and especially its grid layout system.